# How would I be able to create a bot in python that inputs text into a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.4, bots

What code would I use to input text into a box (not edit text, something along the lines of a message bot)?

Say I run the code, it opens a webpage and inputs text into a (e.g.) search box.

Thanks!

Comment: Good code. You definitely don't want to use bad code for something like this.

Comment: Look into [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: @wilbur - Is selenium a tool/module for accessing HTML elements or something like that?

Comment: Not quite. It allows you to interact with a webpage like you would using normal user-input controls (ie mouse, keyboard, etc.)

Comment: Selenium is one way to do what you are describing, but unless you are doing end to end testing (i.e. protractor), likely it's a really inefficient way of accomplishing what you are trying to do. 

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) library to create a bot in Python that inputs texts into a webpage.

According to their description, *"the selenium package is used automate web browser interaction from Python."*

You can install it by typing in the terminal:

`pip install selenium`

Then you'll have to build a set of instructions to tell the program what you want to do.

**Example:**

TASKS:

```
1. open a new Firefox browser
2. load the Yahoo homepage
3. search for “seleniumhq”
4. close the browser
```

CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

Also, read the [Selenium Docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and take a look at a few videos to understand how can you build your own web bot!

Comment: Hey there, I have created an app that goes on a profile, takes the username and tries it as a password. Everything works fine, it's just that I'm finding the username using find_element_by_css_selector, and as you might know, it returns the actual object. How would I convert this to string form? I've tried classes and __repr__ but that would be inefficient in large loops.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is PG old, unused accounts by using the username as the password.